# If check box is checked, don't validate shipping form - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Head here: http://webapps.bcit.ca/A00839579/MDIA3207/Assign4/checkout.html

This is what I want the form to do... If billing form is filled in, but shipping form isn't, the form doesn't validate. If the checkbox is clicked though, only validate billing info. Right now it doesn't validate the shipping info if the check box is un-ticked.

Here's the javascript link (too much to post here): http://webapps.bcit.ca/A00839579/MDIA3207/Assign4/checkout.js

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your javascript :

```
function validateFullCheckout()
{
    var pass_billing = validateCheckout();
    if(!pass_billing)return false;
    if(!document.getElementById('billingcopy').checked)
    {
        var pass_shipping = validateShipCheckout();
        if(!pass_shipping)return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Change

```
<form id="checkoutform" name="checkoutform" onsubmit="return validateCheckout(), return validateShipCheckout();" method="post" action="complete.html">
```

To

```
<form id="checkoutform" name="checkoutform" onsubmit="return validateFullCheckout();" method="post" action="complete.html">
```

Warning... I just typed this here... did not test it.

Note... If you want faster answers, it is much better to boil your question down to the basics and provide a short sample instead of asking people to go fishing through your code.

Comment: That could be: `return !validateCheckout()? false : !document.getElementById('billingcopy').checked? validateShipCheckout() : true;` but maybe that's a bit obfuscated. :-)

Comment: Rob... you are THAT guy that everyone hates inheriting code from :)  Never the less... clean and elegant :)